# Which techniques and filters to apply for Watershed algorithm for object segmentation using skimage (OTSU threshold or Sobel Filter)

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I am trying to object segmentation and the Documentations for `skimage` is confusing as there are diferent techniques for object segmentation given. In some techniques `skimage.filters.sobel()` is used while you look at implementations with `opencv`, mostly `Otsu Threshold` is used. On top of that, some other techniques ask you to apply `closing` followed by `dilation` or find the `distance transform`. Is there a general way to detect and mark the  general objects (**NOT THE COINS OR SYNTHETIC DATA**)?? I have some steps for now and need some guidance for the ordering the steps, detection and specially marking of objects in an image.

```
# read the image
img = skimage.io.imread('image.jpeg')

# convert it to grayscale
gray = skimage.color.rgb2gray(img) 

# denoise it using bilateral or gaussian (IS THIS NECESSARY)??
filtered_img = skimage.filters.gaussian(gray) # skimage.restoration.denoise_bilateral()

# you can apply sobel filter as
sobel_filtered = filters.sobel(gray)

# you can apply OTSU threshold as 
otsu_thresh = skimage.filters.threshold_otsu (gray)
```

What should I be doing now? I am trying to detect and mark garbage and crows if possible like [this image](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fs3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com%2Fwwp-assets%2Fimages%2FScreenshot%2B2019-05-23%2Bat%2B15.37.04.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fai.letsdoitworld.org%2F&tbnid=QBhV3PJJrP1KcM&vet=12ahUKEwjMsdXC9r_pAhVpwnMBHRWwBhUQMygQegUIARDtAQ..i&docid=UCBmelCX3MS7CM&w=1172&h=656&q=garbage%20detection&hl=en&safe=active&ved=2ahUKEwjMsdXC9r_pAhVpwnMBHRWwBhUQMygQegUIARDtAQ)

Comment: “ Documentation is confusing as there are diferent techniques for object segmentation given.“ yes, and these are only the most basic techniques... In the literature there are thousands upon thousands of different techniques... Which to apply and in which order is a result of personal preference, experience, trial and error, and luck.

Comment: @CrisLuengo can you please  provide a link or two for the same too?

Comment: search for "object detection deep learning". As Cris said, there's thousands of methods. Some pre-trained networks might do this out of the box for you. The *basic* segmentation methods (thresholding, sobel + watershed) will be very hard to tune for this task.

Comment: NO NO !! You got me wrong. All I am asking is something using `skimage` only. I do not want to use any AI or something. That I have done many a times. I am trying to learn `Image Processing` but not `Deep Image Recognition`